# Building multiple go plugins under a directory in one shot

Tags: shell, go, find

I have a list of plugins under a subdir. I want to build all of them with a single command. There is an example dir layout.

```
plugins/cat/cat.go
plugins/dog/dog.go
plugins/cow/cow.go
```

I build them right now like:

```
go build -i -buildmode=plugin -o build/cat.so plugins/cat/cat.go
go build -i -buildmode=plugin -o build/dog.so plugins/dog/dog.go
go build -i -buildmode=plugin -o build/cow.so plugins/cow/cow.go
```

There is an other command (because it's in a Makefile), which help me to get closer:

```
# Ex.: make bin-so TARGET=cat
bin-so: builddir
    go build -i -buildmode=plugin -o build/$(TARGET).so plugins/$(TARGET)/$(TARGET).go
```

I want to create a single line which builds these plugins. I found out how I can list the folder names, but I have to use it somehow in the command above.

```
find ./plugins -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk 'sub(/^.*\//, "")'
```

So it will list the name of the folders, these are good to me, but I have to redirect it to the plugin builder command.

I want to have something similar (just an example):

```
find ./plugins -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk 'sub(/^.*\//, "")' | go build -i -buildmode=plugin -o build/$1).so plugins/$1/$1.go
```

Comment: Don't bother with `awk`, just invoke `go build` from find: `find ./plugins -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'f=$(basename $1); go build -i -buildmode=plugin -o build/$f.so plugins/$f/Rf.go' _ {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this in one `find` command with the `-execdir` option that allows you run commands directly on the basename of the files

```
find ./plugins -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c '
    for arg; do
        name="${arg##*./}"
        go build -i -buildmode=plugin -o build/"${name}".so plugins/"${name}"/"${name}".go
    done' _ {} +
```

This is much better than using multiple pipelines after `find` to achieve the same result. Imagine the part within the `sh -c '..'` as a separate script and you are passing the arguments to the script with the names returned `./cow.go` etc.

The advantage of `-execdir` here is you don't need to worry about the immediate paths before the directory names. You get the final base-name of the directories found.

See [Understanding the -exec option of `find` on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/112235) to learn more about each of the options used.